# Sample size planning method differs from analysis method

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, experiment-design, clinical-trials

I have seen some articles using one method for sample size estimation(two sample comparison for means or proportions) and subsequently using regression analysis/non parametric methods.

If I have a planned test statistics $T$ and planned sample size $n_T$ with appropriate power and confidence, is this going to work for regression analysis or non-parametric methods test statistics of which differ from $T$? It is very likely adjusting covariate will not help as the study is not powered to detect alternative by testing regression coefficient for significance.

Comment: Adjusting for covariates that are associated with the response increases power.

Comment: @dipetkov That is assuming that tests without covariate is already significant. However, there is chance that the result is not significant. I am concerned about later rather than former here.

Comment: You are concerned about the case when the result is "not significant". It seems you are saying: If the null is not rejected if covariates are ignored but is rejected if covariates are included, then that's automatically an error? This is not true: if the covariates explain variability in the outcome, this reduces the residual error & increases the power to (correctly) reject the null.

Comment: @dipetkov So if I test proportion difference with experiment designed by t-test sample size and t-test fails, then I run logistic regression to declare significance. That sounds very strange. The association can be purely accidental. I do think it should increase the power, but I could not tell whether this "increase" is purely by chance. It could be bad luck for random sampling. I think I could extrapolate by starting with very naive test and ending with very complicated test. Then I have done a lot of testing. Shouldn't that inflate my type I error as well?

Comment: It sounds strange because the proposed workflow is to forgo t-tests altogether and fit a regression in the first place: one model that will appropriately adjust for covariates known to be important *and* give us the inferential statistics we are interested in. It will help to provide a reference to some of these articles you refer in the question.

Comment: @dipetkov How far can one deviate from planned analysis? Say plan says t-test and somehow investigator found null. The rest is not drafted in plan. Then more complicated machineries are rolled out.

Comment: This veers into the hypothetical of what people are prepared to do to publish their paper. Any number of things I guess, depends on the person. Hence the advice to fit one model and not be tempted into performing a sequence of t-tests.